# Trouble downloading non-JCenter artifacts from bintray

Tags: maven, bintray

My organization is attempting to release some open source into this world and we are starting with some of our libraries.  Currently what I have is published some artifacts into the organization's location.  They are available here and can be seen here:

They are not currently linked to JCenter, because I am OK for now using the explicit repo provided.

However any attempt to resolve them through maven results in:

http://dl.bintray.com/bds/sdk/

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project protex-plugin-integration: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.blackducksoftware.plugins:protex-plugin-inte
gration:jar:1.1.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.blackducksoftware.protex:protex-sdk-client:jar:6.4.2, com.blackducksoftware.protex:protex-
sdk-utilities:jar:6.4.2: Could not find artifact com.blackducksoftware.protex:protex-sdk-client:jar:6.4.2 in bintray-bds-sdk (http://dl.bintray.com/bds/sdk) ->
[Help 1]

This is odd to me since the files are definitely visible via said URL.

Is what I am doing impossible and I *must* submit to JCenter and be accepted first?

The pom contains:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>bintray-bds-sdk</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/bds/sdk</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository is well configured in the POM, but the error reported is true: In the `http://dl.bintray.com/bds/sdk/com/blackducksoftware/protex/protex-sdk-client/6.4.2` location you cannot find the `protex-sdk-client-6.4.2.jar` library; the only existing JAR file has the version *missing* in its name.

You should review the deployment procedure: For some reason (maybe the `finalName`, or some other parametrization in the maven-jar-plugin), the library is being published without the version suffix.

Comment: Deployment procedures as far as I knew did not require that the version was to be specified, only the pom.  In fact, it let me submit to JCenter without any issues which is certainly odd....

Comment: Well, it was just a suggestion. But it's a _fact_ that the jar file has the version suffix missing.

Comment: Very good suggestion.  Fixed the problem!  Thank you much.  The name of the artifact must include version - and while this is not necessarily enforced in a private Artifactory - it most certainly is the required standard in central/bintray, etc.